# Sort a list within a list

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a list of products:

```
public IList<JObject> WhenListProducts()
{
    return new List<JObject>
    {
        JObject.Parse("{ \"gtin\": 1, \"categoryId\": \"cameras\", \"brand\": \"Sony\", \"colour\": \"Blacks\", \"size\": \"Small\", \"quality\": \"Medium\", \"price\": 109.99, \"importance\": 50 }"),
        JObject.Parse("{ \"gtin\": 2, \"categoryId\": \"cameras\", \"brand\": \"Canon\", \"colour\": \"Blacks\", \"size\": \"Large\", \"quality\": \"High\", \"price\": 129.99, \"importance\": 125 }"),
        JObject.Parse("{ \"gtin\": 3, \"categoryId\": \"cameras\", \"brand\": \"Canon\", \"colour\": \"Blacks\", \"size\": \"Small\", \"quality\": \"Medium\", \"price\": 99.99, \"importance\": 75 }"),
        JObject.Parse("{ \"gtin\": 4, \"categoryId\": \"cameras\", \"brand\": \"Nikon\", \"colour\": \"Silvers\", \"size\": \"Large\", \"quality\": \"High\", \"price\": 159.99, \"importance\": 113 }"),
        JObject.Parse("{ \"gtin\": 5, \"categoryId\": \"cameras\", \"brand\": \"Sony\", \"colour\": \"Silvers\", \"size\": \"Small\", \"quality\": \"High\", \"price\": 179.99, \"importance\": 150 }"),
        JObject.Parse("{ \"gtin\": 6, \"categoryId\": \"cameras\", \"brand\": \"Canon\", \"colour\": \"Silvers\", \"size\": \"Large\", \"quality\": \"Low\", \"price\": 116.99, \"importance\": 25 }"),
        JObject.Parse("{ \"gtin\": 7, \"categoryId\": \"cameras\", \"brand\": \"Sony\", \"colour\": \"Blacks\", \"size\": \"Small\", \"quality\": \"High\", \"price\": 189.99, \"importance\": 150 }"),
        JObject.Parse("{ \"gtin\": 8, \"categoryId\": \"cameras\", \"brand\": \"Nikon\", \"colour\": \"Blacks\", \"size\": \"Large\", \"quality\": \"Medium\", \"price\": 129.99, \"importance\": 13 }"),
        JObject.Parse("{ \"gtin\": 9, \"categoryId\": \"cameras\", \"brand\": \"Canon\", \"colour\": \"Reds\", \"size\": \"Small\", \"quality\": \"High\", \"price\": 179.99, \"importance\": 175 }"),
        JObject.Parse("{ \"gtin\": 10, \"categoryId\": \"cameras\", \"brand\": \"Nikon\", \"colour\": \"Silvers\", \"size\": \"Small\", \"quality\": \"High\", \"price\": 185.99, \"importance\": 163 }"),
        JObject.Parse("{ \"gtin\": 11, \"categoryId\": \"cameras\", \"brand\": \"Nikon\", \"colour\": \"Blacks\", \"size\": \"Large\", \"quality\": \"High\", \"price\": 159.99, \"importance\": 113 }"),
        JObject.Parse("{ \"gtin\": 12, \"categoryId\": \"cameras\", \"brand\": \"Nikon\", \"colour\": \"Silvers\", \"size\": \"Small\", \"quality\": \"Low\", \"price\": 69.99, \"importance\": 63 }"),
    };
}
```

And I order them by importance.
In some cases, they have the same importance. In this case, there are 2 products with an importance of 150.
So, I want to make sure they are ordered correctly in that section, so I created some **Sortations** that should re-arrange the products.

```
public List<Sortation> WhenListSortations()
{
    return new List<Sortation>
    {
        new Sortation
        {
            Field = "colour",
            Expression = "Blacks",
            Order = 0
        },
        new Sortation
        {
            Field = "colour",
            Expression = "Greys",
            Order = 1
        },
        new Sortation
        {
            Field = "colour",
            Expression = "Silvers",
            Order = 2
        },
        new Sortation
        {
            Field = "colour",
            Expression = "Whites",
            Order = 3
        },
        new Sortation
        {
            Field = "colour",
            Expression = "Blues",
            Order = 4
        },
        new Sortation
        {
            Field = "colour",
            Expression = "Pinks",
            Order = 5
        },
        new Sortation
        {
            Field = "colour",
            Expression = "Yellows",
            Order = 6
        },
        new Sortation
        {
            Field = "price",
            Expression = "0",
            Order = 7
        },
        new Sortation
        {
            Field = "latestModel",
            Expression = "Yes",
            Order = 8
        }
    };
}
```

And I created a couple of tests:

```
[Test]
    public async Task ShouldHaveHighestImportanceTopAndLowestBottom()
    {
        // Assemble
        var services = SortContext.GivenServices();
        var sortProvider = services.WhenCreateSortProvider();
        var products = services.WhenListProducts();
        var sortations = services.WhenListSortations();

        services.MockSortationProvider.Setup(x => x.ListAsync("cameras")).ReturnsAsync(sortations);

        // Act
        var sortedProducts = await sortProvider.SortAsync(products);

        // Assert
        sortedProducts.First()["importance"].ToString().Should().Be("175");
        sortedProducts.Last()["importance"].ToString().Should().Be("13");
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task ShouldSortEqualImportanceBySortation()
    {
        // Assemble
        var services = SortContext.GivenServices();
        var sortProvider = services.WhenCreateSortProvider();
        var products = services.WhenListProducts();
        var sortations = services.WhenListSortations();

        services.MockSortationProvider.Setup(x => x.ListAsync("cameras")).ReturnsAsync(sortations);

        // Act
        var sortedProducts = await sortProvider.SortAsync(products);

        // Assert
        sortedProducts[0]["importance"].ToString().Should().Be("175");
        sortedProducts[1]["importance"].ToString().Should().Be("163");
        sortedProducts[2]["importance"].ToString().Should().Be("150");
        sortedProducts[3]["importance"].ToString().Should().Be("150");
        sortedProducts[4]["importance"].ToString().Should().Be("125");

        sortedProducts[2]["colour"].ToString().Should().Be("Blacks");
        sortedProducts[3]["colour"].ToString().Should().Be("Silvers");
    }
```

My method to work this out looks like this:

```
public async Task<IList<JObject>> SortAsync(IList<JObject> products)
{
    _productListValidator.Validate(products, "gtin", "categoryId", "importance");

    var categoryId = products[0]["categoryId"]?.ToString();
    var sortations = await _sortationProvider.ListAsync(categoryId);
    if (sortations == null || sortations.Count == 0) return products;

    var orderedSortations = sortations.OrderBy(m => m.Order).ToList();
    var orderedProducts = products.OrderByDescending(m => Convert.ToInt32(m["importance"].ToString())).ToList();
    var groups = orderedProducts.GroupBy(m => m["importance"].ToString());

    var sortedProducts = orderedProducts.OrderBy(a => 1);
    foreach(var group in groups)
    {
        if (group.Count() == 1) continue;
        // TODO: re-order the grouped products by sortation
    }

    var t = sortedProducts.ToList();
    return t;
}
```

As it stands, running my tests with that code will pass the first test, but fail the last test. So, I added my code for sorting the 2 products with 150. It looked like this:

```
var groupProducts = group.ToList().OrderBy(a => 1);
var result = orderedSortations.Aggregate(groupProducts,
    (current, sortation) =>
    {
        if (sortation.Field.Equals("price", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return sortation.Expression.Equals("0") ? 
                current.ThenBy(m => Convert.ToDecimal(m["price"].ToString())) :
                current.ThenByDescending(m => Convert.ToDecimal(m["price"].ToString()));

        return current.ThenByDescending(m => m.ContainsKey(sortation.Field) && m[sortation.Field].ToString().Equals(sortation.Expression));
    }).ToList();
var gtins = result.Select(m => m["gtin"].ToString()).ToList();
sortedProducts = sortedProducts.ThenBy(m => gtins.IndexOf(m["gtin"].ToString()));
```

So the full method looks like this:

```
public async Task<IList<JObject>> SortAsync(IList<JObject> products)
    {
        _productListValidator.Validate(products, "gtin", "categoryId", "importance");
    var categoryId = products[0]["categoryId"]?.ToString();
    var sortations = await _sortationProvider.ListAsync(categoryId);
    if (sortations == null || sortations.Count == 0) return products;

    var orderedSortations = sortations.OrderBy(m => m.Order).ToList();
    var orderedProducts = products.OrderByDescending(m => Convert.ToInt32(m["importance"].ToString())).ToList();
    var groups = orderedProducts.GroupBy(m => m["importance"].ToString());

    var sortedProducts = orderedProducts.OrderBy(a => 1);
    foreach(var group in groups)
    {
        if (group.Count() == 1) continue;

    var groupProducts = group.ToList().OrderBy(a => 1);
    var result = orderedSortations.Aggregate(groupProducts,
        (current, sortation) =>
        {
            if (sortation.Field.Equals("price", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                return sortation.Expression.Equals("0") ? 
                    current.ThenBy(m => Convert.ToDecimal(m["price"].ToString())) :
                    current.ThenByDescending(m => Convert.ToDecimal(m["price"].ToString()));

            return current.ThenByDescending(m => m.ContainsKey(sortation.Field) && m[sortation.Field].ToString().Equals(sortation.Expression));
        }).ToList();
    var gtins = result.Select(m => m["gtin"].ToString()).ToList();
    sortedProducts = sortedProducts.ThenBy(m => gtins.IndexOf(m["gtin"].ToString()));
    }

    var t = sortedProducts.ToList();
    return t;
}
```

The problem with this, is that even though it does order the 2 products correctly, it puts them at the bottom of my list :(
Can someone help me with sorting in it's current position?

You should be able to take the code and run it, let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: You are using current.ThenBy and current.ThenByDescending.  Should the both be either Ascending or Descending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to do this. My method was ok, I just should have sorted by importance **after** I had done sortation:

```
return sortedProducts.OrderByDescending(m => Convert.ToInt32(m["importance"].ToString())).ToList();
```

I removed the first instance of this call and it worked fine.